# Data Conversion from time data type proving tricky

Tags: sql-server

How do you convert a time data type into a float to give hours ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx

Sql server 2012

I have a column called Overtime which is of a time data type. So it will be 1:02 or something similar. What I want is 1.03 hrs . I have tried to convert it to an INT but it gave me an error.

Comment: Datepart?  You may need to expand on your question...

Comment: You realize moving datetime? Or date directly into INT will Not work if there are non-numeric characters stored. Also, use a simple function to achieve this: DATEPART and DATEDIFF/DATEADD can be used to give precise measurements assuming you actually have a properly formatted DATE type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @overtime time  
set @overtime = '1:02'
Select @overtime 
select DatePart(Hour,@overtime) + DatePart(Minute, @overtime) / Convert(Decimal(38,20), 60)
```

Comment: Works in SSMS, but in SSIS it gives u The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_DBTIME2" and "DT_R8"

Comment: Thats odd.  How exactly do you have it set up?  OleDb source with sql command?  Whats the exact error string?  You could update your question or start a new one with SSIS tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @overtime time  
set @overtime = getdate() 
select CONVERT(varchar(15),@overtime,100)
```